# Why NestJS validation pipe fail in unit test when field is missing but skipMissingProperties is true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, testing, nestjs

I have a custom validation pipe in NestJS where I set `skipMissingProperties` to `true`, so when I don't send a field that is decorated with `IsDefined` the validation will not throw exception. For example, if the DTO is:

```
class ModelDTO {
  @IsDefined()
  @IsNumber()
  requiredNumber1: number;

  @IsDefined()
  @IsNumber()
  requiredNumber2: number;
}
```

and the actual object the validation pipe accepts is:

```
{
  requiredNumber2: 1
}
```

it doesn't fail (I save some log in this case).

When I do e2e tests it works fine - I can see the validation pipe continues to the controller and that I get the desired log.

For some reason when I do unit-tests for some reason the same case failes with Bad Request (400) exception, the error message is `requiredNumber2 should not be null or undefined`.

Why the unit-test fails while the e2e works well? (By the way - in manual tests the pipe also works well).

EDIT:
the pipe is:

```
class CustomValidationPipe extends ValidationPipe {
 const OPTIONS = {
  transform: true,
  skipMissingProperties: true,
  whitelist: true,
  forbidNonWhitelisted: false,
  forbidUnknownValues: true,
  transformOptions: {
   enableImplicitConversion: true,
  }
 }
  
 constructor() {
  super(OPTIONS);
 }

 async transform(value, metadata) {
  const objectToValidate = plainToClass(
   metadata.metatype, 
   cloneDeep(value)
  );

  const errors = await validate(
   objectToValidate,
   {
    ...OPTIONS,
    skipMissingProperties: false,
    forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
   }
  )

  if (errors.length > 0) {
   // log
  }

  return super.transform(value, metadata);
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your pipe and how you have it bound?

Comment: Hi, I put it in the post

Comment: What unit tests are you doing that require the use of the pipe?

Comment: Unit test of the pipe itself - i call the transform method to see that the result is as expected and also have a spy on my logger to make sure it logs wheb required